# What kind of style is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, style

I was looking for a description of what kind of style these images are:

[image]

[image]

How can I replicate this style and also would I be better use Photoshop or Illustrator for it?

Answer (score 4):

Both styles, while slightly different, can be summed up as flat vector illustration

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, you can use either tool to accomplish these types of graphics. Adobe Illustrator is primarily a vector-based program, it has some raster-only elements available, such as drop shadows or outer glows. Likewise, Adobe Photoshop now allows you to work with vector-based objects (called smart objects) within the traditionally raster-based program.

It all boils down to the tool you're more comfortable with. I personally am more comfortable with Illustrator and would use it for this type of graphic.

Answer (score 1):

you can use both Photoshop as well as illustrator to draw this object but in Photoshop its some how difficult to arrange some vectors. so i suggest to use Illustrator for this object.